# To create multiple records in salesforce using mule salescloud connector

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am trying to upload many records to salesforce via mule using (create bulk) operation.

I created the flow  as below

```
<flow name="bulk_salesFlow1" doc:name="bulk_salesFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <sfdc:create-bulk config-ref="Salesforce12" type="BulkMule__c" doc:name="Salesforce">
            <sfdc:objects>
                <sfdc:object>
                    <sfdc:inner-object key="Component__c">Transformer</sfdc:inner-object>
                    <sfdc:inner-object key="Use__c">Transforms the payload</sfdc:inner-object>
                </sfdc:object>
                <sfdc:object>
                    <sfdc:inner-object key="Use__c">Iterator</sfdc:inner-object>
                    <sfdc:inner-object key="Component__c">ForEach</sfdc:inner-object>
                </sfdc:object>
            </sfdc:objects>
        </sfdc:create-bulk>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

I am getting error "Element: Object is not allowed to be repeated". I would like to know if I'm trying in the right way, if so what is wrong in the above flow.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just a problem with Mule Studio, and you should be able to run your flow if you just ignore the warnings.

If the warnings bother you, you can always use `<sfdc:objects ref="#[something]"/>` with a list of maps with field names corresponding to your SF object.